# .Htaccess multiple rewrite doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess

*Edited*
.htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3&key=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2 [L]
```

This gives this error:

> Internal Server Error

Update

This code works:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3&key=$4 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3 [L]
```

Only when this line is added it crashes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: More specific rules should appear first.

Comment: @hjpotter92 
Changed to(gives an Internal server error): 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3&key=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2 [L]

Comment: @hjpotter92 I commented with the new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is causing 500 internal error because your rules are infinitely looping. This is because your pattern `^(.*)/(.*)/` also matches rewritten URI `api.php/<whatever>/`.

You need to skip all rules for existing files and directories at top:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3&key=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

I also suggest using anchor `$` in your pattern to safeguard further.

Comment: I've accomplished what i wanted by

Comment: If you note I've also made suggestion of using `$` in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?organisation=$3&key=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?organisation=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ api.php/$1/$2 [L]
```

The above solution is probably also working